# jQuery function is fired twice in IE...?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, windows

I have a function that fires when the scroll bar hits the bottom. For some reason now, IE is firing the event twice. It wasn't doing it before. I don't have a duplicate function, and not have the JS declared twice. It's fine in Opera, FF, Chrome. I don't know why it's doing so in IE. Oh how I hate M$ and this troublesome browser.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){          
        jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
            if  (jQuery(window).scrollTop() == jQuery(document).height() - jQuery(window).height()){
               scrollPost();
            }
        }); 

    });
```

Edit: Actually it's double posting in Safari too. Another browser I don't like.

Comment: You are saying that it wasn't doing it before. Before what?

Comment: I changed the file and method of getting my ajax. It's using pure jQuery now doing a normal ajax call. The problem is not the scrollpost(); function that the above functions calls. It's that it calls the scroll function twice when it hits the bottom. So the process it executes is not the problem. I haven't changed any of my JS files or jQuery version.

Comment: the problem is probably in the jquery scroll() wrapper. I dont have IE to debug it, the if looks correct and I just get scrollPost triggered once in my test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution here.

[Jquery scroll hits twice on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087620/jquery-scroll-hits-twice-on-ie)

Apparently IE and Safari are known for this issue. I had to use the debounce method to keep it from firing twice. 
I used Ben Alman's [dotimeout plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/) and it worked pefectly fixing the IE and Safari issue.